# Objective-c: Finding index an object exists at

Tags: objective-c

```
[arrayName containsObject:myObject]
```

Is there any way to find the index where myObject exists in arrayName?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[arrayName indexOfObject:myObject]
```

[Documented here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObject:) along with a lots of other similar variants that could be useful as well.